# Yoroi and Ledger nano S seed phrase

Tags: wallet, yoroi, ledger, seed-phrase

I'm writting you today because I've a question about seed phrase. I'm a big fan of the cardano project (especially the vision) but sometimes I can be lost with the tech!

To make it simple, I have a Yoroi Wallet and a Ledger Nanos S. I've linked my ledger whith the Yoroi Wallet but it seems I have a seed from the ledger and a seed phrase from the yoroi wallet.
(I first created my yoroi account and then bought a ledger).

Do I need to keep them both or only my ledger seed phrase is okay now? 2 seed phrase is harder to manage for me.

I'm little bit lost so thank you in advance for your help,

Have a great day !

Answer (score 0):

let me give you my case.

i had Y_yoroi wallet with 10K ADA with one Seed Phrase.
i bought L_ledger wallet, installed it and have my Ledger seed phrase (this moment i have 0 ADA here on this wallet).

i moved / sent my 10K ADA from Y_yoroi wallet to the L_ledger wallet.

this current moment the Y_yoroi wallet is empty with 0 ADA.
i can delete it and never use it again.

it is only your decision if you want to keep the Y_yoroi wallet.

Answer (score 0):

and what i would recommend your to do in case you "Stake" your Y_yoroi wallet...

the case with 10K ADA, which is staked from Y_yoroi wallet

1. i moved 9.800 ADA from Y_yoroi to L_ledger wallet.
2. wait 10 days, so that the L_ledger to be staked (active stake) to the pool you staked with your 9.800 ADA. 200 ADA stayed in Y_yoroi wallet
3. the time the L_ledger wallet is staked with 9.800 ADA to the pool, i did withdrawal and unregisted / undelegated the Y_yoroi wallet.
4. wait for 10 days to receive back the 2 ADA from the deposit + the last rewards.
5. moved the last 200 ADA + 2ADA (deposit) + last rewards -> L_ledger wallet.

with this process, i think  is the best way not to loose rewards or any other ADA for the migration to the new wallet.

have a nice week,
Thomas
pool operator for TTS17

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! 

It truly helps me a lot but I'm not sure to understand perfectly. When you say you moved it into your ledger I don't visualize it. Ledger Live has no cardano wallet so where do you send it? 

I'm asking myslef that maybe my ledger device (which is linked to yoroi) keeps my seed inside the device? It would be great because it means that It keeps it for me and I have only the seed phrase of the ledger to take care of.

At the end I would like to have only one seed phrase, use the security of ledger and continuing having staking rewards.

Comment: ok i though you have finished the whole installation properly.

let me text you something more

Answer (score 0):

ok, check the whole process.

1. you Install Ledger Live and you connect your Ledger.
2. you move to the left bottom side, option "manager"
3. this moment you will be requested to connect your Ledger Nano X and give your PIN
4. there, you can find many Crypto. Install Cardano
5. Cardano will not be inserted in Ledger Live.
6. this moment you have to open Yoroi again
7. go to the main Page, where you find all your wallet, and "ADD NEW WALLET"
8. then you "CONNECT TO HARDWARE WALLET"
9. click on "CARDACO"
10. select "LEDGER HARDWARE WALLET"
11. select "STANDARD WALLET"
12. this moment you have to connect your Ledger NANO X device.
13. when you successfully import this "wallet", you will find a new wallet, which will be the Ledger wallet. - unfortunately, there is no Cardano in Ledger Live, but for my opinion is not a problem.
14. when you "add" this wallet, you are ready to find a "received" address and take the steps i mentioned in my previous answer.

i hope is clear my answer and can help you.

if you need more, dont hesitate to ask, i am happy to assist.
if that helps, dont forget to vote our answers :)

best regards
TTS17

Comment: Hi, 
Thank you again for your answer and your pedagogy ! I was sleeping! It is awesome to have such space in the Cardano Ecosystem ! 

I'm still a little bit confused because I don't see the differences between the "new wallet" on Yoroi that I need to create. 

It seems that I have done this instruction with my current Yoroi Wallet. This Wallet is called "Yoroi Ledger" and below this name I even have the logo of ledger and write "wallet ledger".
I installed Ledger Live on my ledger nano S months ago and Yesterday I just verified that I was on the latest version which is the case.

Comment: My ledger nano S is updated (I checked it yesterday on my computer with Ledger Live in the "manager") and I have only the Cardano app on it. 

So, do I still need to open a new one or this current one is a "ledger wallet"?

It is not easy to distinguish the subtility between both so that's why I'm trying to put as much details as possible. 

If I have to open a new one it is okay, my concern is about security (be sure that my ADA are on my cold wallet), staking (on Yoroi with a pool) and having 1 seed phrase (the seed phrase from ledger).

Thank you in advance it is so helpful !

Comment: sorry but with names i confuse a bit :)
each Hardware wallet, Ledger NANO X / S in your case, will have its own "object" in yoroi.

if you had so long a Ledger NANO S in yoroi, please keep it until you import the new one, and then if you want -> fund your ADA from NANO S to NANO X wallet.

but you need to import the NANO X to your yoroi.

Comment: my Friend,

please define what you want to do and then i am happy to assist you.
1. do you have / want to have only this 2 wallets? ledger S and Ledger X ?
2. do you have any other wallet?

please make more clear what you want to achieve

Comment: I only have 1 ledger which is is a Nano S (I can only install 3 applications on it) and I have only 1 Cardano wallet on yoroi. 
I don't plan having a new ledger (I'm only in cardano) and I'm happy with juste one wallet on Yoroi. 
I would like to have my Ada coins secured in my cold wallet (ledger nano S) and staking on Yoroi. Yoroi must just be a interface to visualize my coin but not to protect it.
This would allow me to have One seed phrase from Ledger which is easier for me to manage.

Comment: sorry but in the begin, in your main post, you said you have 1 seed phrase from yoroi wallet, and 1 seed phrase for the Ledger.
 1 Ledger device gives you only one Seed Phrase for all your wallets for the different of coins you have. for that reason all the time i was giving you guide as i believed you have 2 wallets = 1 software wallet from yoroi, and 1 hardware Ledger wallet using it in yoroi. ------ if you had 2 wallets, for your question....i would keep the Ledger seed phrase , move all my ada to this wallet, and then wouldnt use my yoroi software wallet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for your time ! 
English is not my native language so maybe it caused this unclear information, I have a lack of vocabulary so It is hard to put details sometimes. I'm sorry ! 
So, it seems that all was good? My current wallet on Yoroi is a ledger wallet (it is what is written) so I have nothing to do? 

I first opened the yoroi wallet and they gave me a seed phrase because it was a classic Yoroi wallet. And then, with my ledger S,  I linked it to my ledger so maybe the seed from Yoroi become useless? It should be in my ledger which store all the keys?

Comment: So my last question is what I do with the Yoroi Seed Phrase, should I keep it or it is useless because it is my ledger which is important now?

Comment: just to be safe, keep it.

but you need to understand what is for what.
i will ask you again, the seed phrase is for the software yoroi wallet? or for the Ledger wallet ?
till now, i dont understand if you have 2 wallets or one.